# Multiple python3 versions in /usr/lib/ and other places: python3, python3.7, python3.8

Tags: apt, python, python3, pip

I have multiple python3 versions that are causing problems. See here: [Problems with upgrading pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58386953/i-have-a-issue-with-pip3/58389148#58389148)
How can I delete all the versions except 3.8?

Edit:

```
$ which python python2 python3 pip pip2 pip3
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/pip3
$ which python python2 python3 pip pip2 pip3 | xargs ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 303 Mar 30  2019 /usr/bin/pip3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   7 Mar  4  2019 /usr/bin/python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Mar  4  2019 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 13 02:33 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.7
```

Edit2:

```
$ locate \*/bin/python\?.\?
/snap/core/6673/usr/bin/python3.5
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/31/usr/bin/python3.6
/usr/bin/python3.7
```

Edit3:
Does the following mean I have python3.8 installed?

```
/usr/lib$ ls -d python*
python2.7  python3  python3.7  python3.8
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure how I installed them.

Comment: I don't have the command `updateb`. Ubuntu version is 19.04.

Comment: I have python3.8 in my /usr/lib/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100023/discussion-between-user-dz-and-hyrial).